# Is there a word for "game literate"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If you're able to read and understand the written word, you're literate.

If you're able to count and understand mathematical concepts, you're numerate.

If you're able to play games and understand essential game tropes/concepts/mechanics, you're...?

Example: John could pick up and play any game without much difficulty, because he was very (game literate).

I would think the technical latin-derived equivalent would be approximately *ludate*, from *ludus* (game), which would probably be bastardized into *luderate*, similar to the way we do words with *-aholic* from alcohol, which is etymologically incoherent.

Having said all that, the words I've suggested above don't seem to exist. Is there anything else that would fit this definition?

Comment: Games like ... Monopoly or chess?

Comment: I'm guessing he means video games, computer games, on-line games. (Only senior citizens like me have heard of Monopoly of Chess... except for the *computer* versions of those games.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you're looking for is, in fact, *game literate* (also *video game literate* or hyphened: *game-literate*). It's based on the same pattern as "computer literate". Yeah, I know you used this already in your question, but you should definitely reconsider because it's already a word people use:

- [Readers should get **game-literate**](https://www.theguardian.com/books/booksblog/2008/feb/07/readersshouldgetgameliterat1)
- [Good dungeon crawler for very **game literate** 9 year old](https://www.reddit.com/r/boardgames/comments/5iwcnc/good_dungeon_crawler_for_very_game_literate_9/)
- [The Meaning and Relevance of Video Game Literacy](http://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2510&context=clcweb):

  - > Who gets to be **video game literate**?
- [The 43 Things You Absolutely, Positively Must Do To Be **Game-Literate**](http://www.gamingaswomen.com/posts/2015/03/43-things-absolutely-positively-must-game-literate/)